# Where is the maximum of the Gaussian?

Tags: calculus

The maximum of the envelope $\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ is supposed to be at $x=0$. Why is this the case?

Comment: Do you know where the maximum of $1/e^{x}$ is?

Comment: Extrema of a function are located at points where the derivative vanishes; in your case $x=0$ is such a point. If you compute the second derivative, and evaluate it at $x=0$ you'll find $-1/\sigma^2$, and since this is negative, this indicates it is a local maximum. Another way to see it: plot the function.

Comment: Have you drawn a graph of the function to see what it looks like?

Comment: $e^{\mathrm{blah}}$ is an increasing function of $\mathrm{blah}$, so the maximum of $e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ occurs at the maximum of $-x^2/(2\sigma^2)$.